# How can I Update value of key In JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I am using **_underscore**. I want to rename value of particular key.

```js
var users = [{
    "_id": { "$oid":"3426" },
    "name":"peeter"
}, {
    "_id": { "$oid":"5a027" },
    "name":"ken"
}, {
    "_id": { "$oid":"5999" },
    "name":"karmal"
}];
 
var index = _.find(users, function(o) { return o._id.$oid == '5999'; });
console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

In above output in `console.log(index)`, I want to edit value of key(name), meaning add karmal-Copy.

**Desired output**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5999"
    },
    "name": "karmal-Copy"
}
```

I want only add -Copy with key(name) value.

Comment: Isn't `index['name'] += '-Copy'` or `index.name += '-Copy'` enough? Though, you would change the original value like that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just update the found object.

```js
var users = [{ _id: { $oid: "3426" }, name: "peeter" }, { _id: { $oid: "5a027" }, name:"ken" }, { _id: { $oid: "5999" }, name: "karmal" }],
    item = _.find(users, function(o) { return o._id.$oid == '5999'; });

if (item) {               // check if item exists
    item.name += '-Copy'; // update property
}
console.log(users);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think there should be a huge warning, that the reference will be changed, and running it twice will add `-Copy-Copy`

Comment: you could add a check if necessary to prevent multiple suffixes.

Comment: I have to say I disagree, the OP should be aware that he is changing the original list item if he does this, this could have serious consequences if you are changing a reference

Answer (score 0):

With the power of Higher-order functions

```
var users = [
    {"_id":{"$oid":"3426"},
    "name":"peeter"
    },
    {"_id":{"$oid":"5a027"},
    "name":"ken"
    },
    {"_id":{"$oid":"5999"},
    "name":"karmal"
    }
  ];

var getSpecific$oid=function(oid){ 
    return function(obj) { return obj["_id"]["$oid"]===oid; };
  }

var addExtensionInName=function(extension){ 
    return function(obj){ 
        var rObj = {};
        rObj["_id"]=obj["_id"]
        rObj["name"]=obj["name"] +"-"+extension;
        return rObj;
      };
  }

var index=users.filter(getSpecific$oid("5999")).map(addExtensionInName("copy"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if(users[i]._id.$oid == 5999) {
        users[i].name += "-Copy"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```js
var users = [
  {"_id":{"$oid":"3426"},
  "name":"peeter"
  },
  {"_id":{"$oid":"5a027"},
  "name":"ken"
  },
  {"_id":{"$oid":"5999"},
  "name":"karmal"
  }
];
 
var index = _.find(users, function(o) { 
    if(o._id.$oid == '5999'){
      o.name += '-Copy';
      return o._id.$oid == '5999'; 
    }
  });

console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Though it works, this will now add a check for every item inside the find method and you are changing a reference inside the find method